# Get_prefix discord bot error (async function wont work)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a custom prefix command that uses JSON to get a prefix for the said server but it's not working for some reason. What I think is happening is that my async function is working properly but I can't figure out what is happening.

**Code**
This is the code without the unneeded discord bot things

```py
async def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('storage\pp.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)


        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]    



#Defining Bot:
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= get_prefix)


@Bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('storage\pp.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)


    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '.'

    with open('storage\pp.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
        print(f'{guild.id} Joined')



@Bot.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('storage\pp.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)


    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('storage\pp.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
        print(f'{guild.id} Left')

#the command

@Bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def prefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open('storage\pp.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)


    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('storage\pp.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
        await ctx.send(f'***Prefix has been changed to***  ✅  ``{prefix}``')
```

**And here is my error when I tried running it.**

```
return await value
  File "c:\Users\beaty\Desktop\junk\code\python\pinky\bot.py", line 101, in get_prefix
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
KeyError: '67685146592647##' #I took out two letters of that key because I don't know what it's referring to.
```

**Full error:**

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\beaty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\beaty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 979, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\beaty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 975, in process_commands
    ctx = await self.get_context(message)
  File "C:\Users\beaty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 886, in get_context
    prefix = await self.get_prefix(message)
  File "C:\Users\beaty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 831, in get_prefix
    ret = await discord.utils.maybe_coroutine(prefix, self, message)
  File "C:\Users\beaty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 343, in maybe_coroutine
    return await value
  File "c:\Users\beaty\Desktop\junk\code\python\pinky\bot.py", line 101, in get_prefix
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
KeyError: '6768514659264758##'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in using an `async` function there (but to be honest it's useless cause there's nothing `async` about it), if you try to use a normal function the error won't magically disappear. If actually take a look at your JSON file you won't see the `6768514659264758##` key, you need to use a `try/except` block and set a default prefix.

```py
async def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('storage\pp.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    try:
        prs = prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
    except KeyError:
        prs = "your default prefix"
    return prs
```

You can shorten the code with the `dict.get` method:

```py
async def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('storage\pp.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes.get(str(message.guild.id), "your default prefix")
```

Comment: It works but I'm having problems with my path when i uploaded it to heroku